# How to get rid of reinitialization of Matlab trackerGNN for multiple scenarios?

Tags: matlab, estimation, tracker

Consider a tracking task in MATLAB for 80 diffrerent observations with

```
 tracker = trackerGNN('Assignment','Auction')

 for time =0:79
 detections = {objectDetection(time,[1;2+time/30;3-time/30]); % Using default values on the detection ...
 objectDetection(time, [10+time/20;0+time/20;0-time/20])};

 [confirmedTracks, tentativeTracks] = tracker(detections, time);
 time=time+1;
 end
```

When this task is completed I have another one. For example the same codes as above but just use

```
 detections = {objectDetection(time,[1;2+time/20;3-time/20]); % Using default values on the detection ...
 objectDetection(time, [10+time/30;0+time/30;0-time/30])};
```

This must also start from time=0 and this is where I have problems. To be able to run the second scenario either I have to reinitialize the tracker with

```
tracker = trackerGNN('Assignment','Auction')
```

before the for-loop, or alternatively I can use the command

```
release (tracker)
tracker=tk;
```

If this code part was defined at the beginning of the code

```
tracker = trackerGNN('Assignment','Auction')
tk=tracker;
```

The problem is that the first version, namely reinitialization takes 5 seconds for each scenario and the second way via using release(), takes about 4 seconds. If I want to simulate thousands of scenarios I stuck with the excessive loss of time due to just reinitialization of the tracker.

If I dont do reinitialization then the tracker is stuck to the previous scenario and it expects to continue with time=80. If I don't do that it gives me an error because it is called out of sequance detections and the tracker is adjusted to terminate. I can of course change it not to terminate but this also doesnt solve the issue that the tracker is still stuck to the previous scenario..

Is there any way to get rid of reinitialization time lag in MATLAB?